# CanvasJS Chart Time Going Backwards?

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I've got a weird issue with my charts, the date seems to be going backwards, any idea of what I am doing wrong.

I've looked through my documentation and can't quite see what I am doing wrong.

Documentation is here: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/formatting-date-time/

Here is a screenshot...
[image]

and here is my code...

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {      
backgroundColor: "#2e3037",
animationEnabled: true,
axisY :{
    includeZero: false,
    //prefix: '$',
    gridColor: '#79797c',
    labelFontSize: 16,
    labelFontColor: "#79797c",
    valueFormatString: "$#.00"
},
axisX: {
    gridColor: '#79797c',
    valueFormatString: "MM/DD/YY",
    labelAngle: -50,
    interval:1, 
    intervalType: "day", 
    labelFontColor: '#79797c',
    labelFontSize: 10,
},
toolTip: {
    //shared: "true",
    fontColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "#6b60d4",
    content: "${y}",
},
data: [{        
    type: "area", 
    showInLegend: false,
    color: '#6b60d4',
    fillOpacity: .1,
    name: "Price at the Close of the Day",
    prefix: '$',
    markerSize: 0,        
    dataPoints: [
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 16), y: 1050.26}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 17), y: 1024.69}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 18), y: 1012.97}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 19), y: 1037.36}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 20), y: 1150.5}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 21), y: 1049.09}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 22), y: 999.64}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 23), y: 984.47}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 24), y: 1061.78}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 25), y: 1046.37}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 26), y: 1048.58}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 27), y: 1109.08}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 28), y: 1231.58}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 29), y: 1169.96}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 30), y: 1063.75}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 31), y: 1111.31}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 01), y: 1026.19}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 02), y: 917.47}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 03), y: 970.87}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 04), y: 827.59}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 05), y: 695.08}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 06), y: 785.01}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 07), y: 751.81}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 08), y: 813.55}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 09), y: 877.88}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 10), y: 850.75}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 11), y: 811.24}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 12), y: 865.27}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 13), y: 840.98}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 02, 14), y: 888.82}
    ]
}]
});
chart.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript date object, month starts from 0 (for Jan) to 11 (for Dec). Please refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.

In your case, as there are x-values `new Date(2018, 01, 29)`, `new Date(2018, 01, 30)`, `new Date(2018, 01, 31)`, it corresponds to March 1st, 2nd and 3rd respectively. And there follows x-values from `new Date(2018, 02, 01)` which corresponds to Mar 1st again. So soon after Mar 3rd (i.e. `new Date(2018, 01, 31)`) again it switches back to Mar 1st (i.e. `new Date(2018, 02, 01)`).

Making the corresponding changes to month works fine in this scenario. Below is the working code:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {      
backgroundColor: "#2e3037",
animationEnabled: true,
axisY :{
    includeZero: false,
    //prefix: '$',
    gridColor: '#79797c',
    labelFontSize: 16,
    labelFontColor: "#79797c",
    valueFormatString: "$#.00"
},
axisX: {
    gridColor: '#79797c',
    valueFormatString: "MM/DD/YY",
    labelAngle: -50,
    interval:1, 
    intervalType: "day", 
    labelFontColor: '#79797c',
    labelFontSize: 10,
},
toolTip: {
    //shared: "true",
    fontColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "#6b60d4",
    content: "${y}",
},
data: [{        
    type: "area", 
    showInLegend: false,
    color: '#6b60d4',
    fillOpacity: .1,
    name: "Price at the Close of the Day",
    prefix: '$',
    markerSize: 0,        
    dataPoints: [
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 16), y: 1050.26}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 17), y: 1024.69}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 18), y: 1012.97}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 19), y: 1037.36}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 20), y: 1150.5}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 21), y: 1049.09}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 22), y: 999.64}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 23), y: 984.47}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 24), y: 1061.78}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 25), y: 1046.37}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 26), y: 1048.58}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 27), y: 1109.08}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 28), y: 1231.58}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 29), y: 1169.96}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 30), y: 1063.75}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 00, 31), y: 1111.31}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 01), y: 1026.19}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 02), y: 917.47}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 03), y: 970.87}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 04), y: 827.59}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 05), y: 695.08}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 06), y: 785.01}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 07), y: 751.81}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 08), y: 813.55}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 09), y: 877.88}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 10), y: 850.75}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 11), y: 811.24}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 12), y: 865.27}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 13), y: 840.98}, 
        {x: new Date(2018, 01, 14), y: 888.82}
    ]
}]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```